# ways are there to distribute $7$ (identical) apples, $6$ oranges and $7$ pears among $3$ different people with each person getting at least $1$ pear?

Tags: combinatorics

> How many ways are there to distribute $7$ (identical) apples, $6$ oranges and $7$ pears among $3$ different people with each person getting at least $1$ pear?

Below are my workings but I am not sure if they are correct, looking for some help, thanks!

**Using the inclusion/exclusion principle:**

Include the number of ways to distribute them such that at most $\color\red3$ people have pears:

$$3^7\cdot\binom{3}{\color\red3}\cdot\color\red3^6=1594323$$

Exclude the number of ways to distribute them such that at most $\color\red2$ people have pears:

$$3^7\cdot\binom{3}{\color\red2}\cdot\color\red2^6=419904$$

Include the number of ways to distribute them such that at most $\color\red1$ person has pears:

$$3^7\cdot\binom{3}{\color\red1}\cdot\color\red1^6=6561$$

---

Hence the number of ways to distribute them such that each person has pears is:

$$1594323-419904+6561=1180980$$

Comment: This number is far too large.  You are, I think, treating the various apples (say) as distinguishable.  There aren't, for example, $3^7$ ways to distribute the apples, far from it.  Hint:  apply [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) to each type of fruit separately.

Comment: @lulu thanks, could you help me through this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's important to recognize that the fruit (of a given type) are meant to be indistinguishable.  Thus, factors like $3^7$ should not appear.

We will use [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)):

For the pears, we need the number of $3-$tuples of positive integers that add to $7$.  That's $$\binom 62=15$$

For the apples, we need the number of $3-$tuples of non-negative integers that add to $7$.  That's $$\binom {7+3-1}{7}=36$$

For the oranges, we need the number of $3-$tuples of non-negative integers that add to $6$.  That's $$\binom {6+3-1}{6}=28$$

Finally, the answer is the product $$\boxed {15\times 36\times 28 = 15120}$$

Note:  as always with combinatorics, it's always a good idea to check the arithmetic carefully.

Comment: I see where I went wrong, thanks!